# C - Pointer array of structs adds 3 items then each new item added blanks out previous items besides first 2

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a c program to parse a paragraph of text and created 3 structs to aid in the process where a block contains lines, a line contains words, and a word holds the text.

```
typedef struct word {
    int length;
    char* text;
} Word;

typedef struct line {
    int charachterCount;
    int numberOfWords;
    Word* words;
} Line;

typedef struct textBlock {
    int numberOfLines;
    Line* lines;
} Block;
```

When I try to add words to my line struct, the first 3 add fine. Once I add a fourth word, the 3rd word becomes "" and only the first 2 words and the 4th words record accurately. When I add a 5th word, the 3rd and 4th words become "" and only the 1st,2nd, and 5th words record accurately. And the cycle continues when more words are added, only the 1st, 2nd, and last words added record, every other address contains "". Here is ouput I printed:

This is a key to what information is being printed:

```
Altered line: [EACH WORD IN LINE IS PRINTED FOLLOWED BY A SPACE]  : Ch#=[CHARACHTER COUNT], Word#=[WORD COUNT], LastAdd=[ADDRESS OF LAST WORD IN ARRAY], tAdd=[ADDRESS OF TEXT IN LAST WORD IN ARRAY]
```

```
Line #: 13
Text Given: the Northeastern United States and the Southern United 

Altered line: the  : Ch#=4, Word#=1, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00ac0, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00ac8
Altered line: the Northeastern  : Ch#=17, Word#=2, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00ad0, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00ad8
Altered line: the Northeastern United  : Ch#=24, Word#=3, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00ae0, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00ae8
Altered line: the Northeastern  States  : Ch#=31, Word#=4, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00af0, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00af8
Altered line: the Northeastern   and  : Ch#=35, Word#=5, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b00, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b08
Altered line: the Northeastern    the  : Ch#=39, Word#=6, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b10, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b18
Altered line: the Northeastern    Southern  : Ch#=48, Word#=7, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b20, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b28
Altered line: the Northeastern     United  : Ch#=55, Word#=8, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b30, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b38
Returning line: the Northeastern     United  : Ch#=55, Word#=8, LastAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b30, tAdd=0x7fa7d9d00b38
```

Here is the code that is producing it:

```
void addWordToLine(Line* line, Word word) {
    line->charachterCount = line->charachterCount + word.length + 1;
    line->words[line->numberOfWords] = word;
    line->numberOfWords = line->numberOfWords + 1;
}

Line convertTextToLine(char* text) {
    Line newLine = emptyLine();
    Word word;
    char* newWord = malloc(sizeof(text));
    int textIndex = 0;
    int wordsIndex = 0;
    int wordIndex = 0;

    while (text[textIndex] != NIL) {
        if (text[textIndex] == ' ' || text[textIndex] == '\n') {
            newWord[wordIndex] = '\0';
            if (wordIndex != 0) {
                word = buildWord(newWord);
                newLine.words = realloc(newLine.words, sizeof(newLine.words) + sizeof(word) * 2);
                addWordToLine(&newLine, word);
                printf("Altered line: ");
                printLine(newLine);
                wordsIndex = wordsIndex + 1;
            }
            wordIndex = 0;
        } else {
            newWord[wordIndex] = text[textIndex];
            wordIndex = wordIndex + 1;
        }
        textIndex = textIndex + 1;
    }
    if (wordIndex != 0) {
        newWord[wordIndex] = '\0';
        word = buildWord(newWord);
        newLine.words = realloc(newLine.words, sizeof(newLine.words) + sizeof(word));
        addWordToLine(&newLine, word);
    }

    printf("Returning line: ");
    printLine(newLine);

    return newLine;
}

Word buildWord(char* text) {
    Word word;
    word.count = 1;
    word.text = malloc(sizeof(text));
    strcpy(word.text, text);
    word.length = getTextLength(text);
    return word;
}

Word emptyWord() {
    Word newWord;
    newWord.count = 1;
    newWord.length = 0;
    newWord.text = malloc(sizeof(char));
    return newWord;
}

Line emptyLine() {
    Line newLine;
    newLine.charachterCount = 0;
    newLine.numberOfWords = 0;
    newLine.words = malloc(sizeof(Word));
    return newLine;
}
```

Any help on why this is happening and how I can fix is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is `Line newLine = emptyLine();` doing? Perhaps this should be a pointer? Or you should be passing `newLine` into the function `emptyLine(&newLine)`

Comment: `char* newWord = malloc(sizeof(text));` allocates enough space for a single `char *`.  I don't think this is what you want unless.  Even if `buildWord()` somehow resizes this, it still is probably not intended.  I think perhaps you want `newWord = malloc(strlen(text));` (Note - `strlen()` is an evil function, prone to failure, but it demonstrates grabbing enough space for your string instead of a pointer.  Ugh - `sizeof(newLine.words) + sizeof(word) * 2)` does same thing.  these need to be size of array, not pointers...  Ok, every instance of your `malloc()` calls need changing.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the incoming text? If so maybe you don't need to bother with `newWord` and you can just modify `text` directly and do away with the `malloc`. If not it would be good to declare `text` as `const` like `Line convertTextToLine(const char * text)`

Comment: If `text` is a pointer, then `sizeof(text)` is the size for that pointer. On a PC this is typically 4 bytes. 
`malloc(strlen(text))` can also be dangerous, since you may want to store the termination. I would go with `malloc(strlen(text)+1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael! Changing the allocated space fixed it, I misunderstood what sizeof() was representing.

Comment: It should be `malloc(strlen(text)+1)` to allow space for the trailing null byte.